# Error while installing TensorFlow on Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10

Tried fixing it by following the suggestion but, as you'll see, still have issues:

C:\Users\xxx>pip install tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for tensorflow

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

> > >

C:\Users\xxx>python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

Collecting pip

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)

```
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 773kB/s
```

Installing collected packages: pip

Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1

```
Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:

  Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
```

Successfully installed pip-20.0.2

C:\Users\xxx>pip install tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

In all probability, you have installed Python 32-bit version instead of Python 64-bit version, hence the error. Make sure you download a version from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ with the x64 bit in the description, like

> Download Windows x86-64 web-based installer

Comment: As I am working with Anaconda, I installed the TensorFlow through its environments packages. 
As for the suggestion in Timbus' response, I have python in 64 and 32 bit, but the path is set for 64. In any case, it is solved from my side.

Comment: Uninstall then the 32-bit, in order to avoid such problems as above. Glad your problem is solved.